# How to maintain EPI terminal connection from an EJB using CCI?

Tags: cics, cci

I am trying to convert our JAVA applet that access a back-end CICS 3270 application to be more of a web/HTML5 based.
The application has a login screen that will bring user to a menu of choice that calls other screens. Each screens can call one or more other screens.
I am able to connect to the 3270 application using CCI but the problem is on how to keep the connection alive and keep track of the screen position until the user log off from our application.
I do not see any build-in "session" management in CCI, do I need to maintain this myself? For example: saving the InteractionSpec and the EPIScreenRecord objects (this might not even works).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the EPI Support classes in the com.ibm.ctg.epi package rather than the CCI, i.e a Terminal, Screen and a JavaGateway this would allow your application to manually control the connection and terminal(s). See
[Javadoc](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZHFX_9.1.0/basejavadoc/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, we are already using the EPI support classes in our applet, but we would like to convert the applet program into an html based application. I believe that we can use EJB stateful bean in order to maintain the connection. I was able to run a successful test using the CCI classes in order to get WebSphere to manage the connection.